# How to read commented line in a file and copy the same ..as it is to other file in shell script

Tags: shell

I have file (Name test.func) with a comments as below

```
   #--------------------
   # DOG $ CAT NAMES
   #--------------------
   Brownie
   Blacky
   Vicky
   Pammy

   #--------------
   # MOBILE & LAPTOP NAMES
   #--------------
   Lenovo
   Oppo
   Realme
```

The code i have written is as below

```
    TestFile=$(cat /usr/test.func)
    for line in $TestFile
        echo "line is $line"
        if  [[ "$line" == *"#"* ]]; then
            echo "$line is commented"
            echo "$line" >>test_copy.func
            echo " "
        fi
    
       if ...
         #Some other logic here
       fi
    done
```

Output is giving as below (in test_copy.func)

```
     line is #----------
     #-------- is commented

     line is #
     # is commented

     line is DOG

     line is &

     line is CAT

     line is NAMES

 *Some logic is performed*


     line is #----------
     #-------- is commented

     line is #
     # is commented

     line is MOBILE

     line is &

     line is LAPTOP

     line is NAMES

    *Some logic is performed*
```

Expected output in test_copy.func should be as below

```
    #--------------------
    # DOG $ CAT NAMES
    #--------------------
    *Output as per the logic*

    #--------------
    # MOBILE & LAPTOP NAMES
    #--------------
   *Output as per the logic*
```

Commented lines are splited in the actual output.
But Expected result should be as in the source file
Can anyone help me to resolve this issue
 [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4sJ4.jpg)

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts. Please do mention logic of getting your expected output in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: `grep '^[[:space:]]*#' test > test-comments`?

Comment: Generated output file from script i.e. test_copy.func should have the commented lines ...as in source file i.e. test.func Commented lines should print as it is ..in source file.

Comment: The code for copying the comments is easily done with `awk` or `sed`.  Probably `#Some other logic here` can be incorporated easily in those tools as well.

Comment: Do you really want to consider any line that merely contains a `#` to be a comment?  The expression `*"#"*` will match `foo#bar`, which is probably not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
TestFile=$(cat /usr/test.func)
for line in $TestFile
```

does not loop over the lines of the file, but over the "words" (contiguous strings of non-whitespace characters).  The variable `TestFile` contains the contents of the file, but the `for` loop is subject to field splitting.  In other words, if the file contains "foo bar baz", the loop is equivalent to `for line in foo bar baz; do ...`.  This is a very fragile construction, as it is also subject to glob expansion, etc.  For example, if the file contains wildcards (eg `foo * bar`), those wildcards will be expanded (and `foo * bar` expands to a string that contains all the names in the current directory).

The standard way to iterate over the lines of a file is
`while read line; do ... done < /usr/test.func`

But this is terribly slow and should generally be avoided.  Tools like `sed` and `awk` are far more appropriate.   It's normally a bad idea to read through a file on multiple passes, but `while read` is so slow that you could read the file 50 times with other tools before you would likely begin to notice.  You probably don't want to copy lines that merely contain a # (as the `*"#"*` expression will do, but only want to copy lines that begin with #, but that's a different question).  I would recommend either:

```
sed -n -e '/^\s*#/p' /usr/test.func > test_copy.func
while read -r line; do some_other_logic "$line"; done < /usr/test.func
```

or:

```
awk '/^\s*#/{print > "test_copy.func"}
    { some other logic here }' /usr/test.func
```